# what happens to users comments if user is deleted and Foreign key is set to models.SET_NULL

Tags: django, django-models

I was just curious what happens to users comments when user is deleted. Specially in the example below example

```
Comment(models.models):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.Charfield(max_length=1000)
```

Example of the comment:

This is a comment
     -by Samir Tendulkar (`{{user.first_name}}` `{{user.last_name}}`)

Now lets say the user is deleted

This is a comment
     -by `??` (`{{user.first_name}}` `{{user.last_name}}`)

Is there a way to add a default user as anonymous user

1) This is a comment
     -by `Anonomous User` (`{{user.first_name}}` `{{user.last_name}}`)

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) were not very clear on this

Comment: Well like the trigger indicates, they still exist, but the `author` field is now `NULL` (so `None` in Python).

Comment: so how will the author show in the comments once the user is deleted. and also is there a way to add default in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect if the comment has an user and act accordingly, for example if the comment has an author display the name, if not , then display anonymous user::

```
This is a comment -by
{%if comment.author%}
{{comment.author.first_name}} {{comment.author.last_name}}
{%else%}
 Anonomous User
{%endif%}
```